# Would this vacuum-tube logic question be a good fit for the site?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

In StackExchange ElectricalEngineering there is the question:

Were Vacuum Tube Computers made of Logic Gates?

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/704329/were-vacuum-tube-computers-made-of-logic-gates

Is StackExchange - Retrocomputing the more appropriate area?

Note: I have no idea if or when it is appropriate to move a question. How to move a question if that is even possible. Or how you are can inform people in one forum about a topic of interest in another forum.

It really comes down to how do you inform people of an interesting question in another forum.

Comment: check out https://www.youtube.com/@UsagiElectric, he's building a 1bit computer from vacuum tubes, and restoring a bendix G15 machine from somewhen in the 1960s that also used them

Comment: Please do not delete this question in 24 hours, it is a good question to have around. But it definitely belongs on the meta site and not on the main site.

Comment: Deleting the question in 24 hours could be interpreted as vandalism.  You may find our users with enough reputation undeleting it.

Comment: Waving the white flag, I surrender... Deleted the 24 hours deletion.

Comment: The logic in [analog computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer) would have involved [comparators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator).

Comment: Evidently, were such a question to appear in SE:RC, it would be closed due to any answer being based on opinion.

Comment: @dave Please note I'm sneaking in the words "correctly written answer" so not based on any of my attempts. If a correctly written answer to the question was based on referenced extracts from patents, textbooks, engineering society publications, reports and reviews from or relevant to the 1940s period then wouldn't this become a valid question for SE:RC? Opinion is then expressed in the SE voting.

Comment: @PDP11 - the problem, I think, is that the original question is not clear on what it is really asking; thus "opinions" creep in based on having to interpret the intent. The question could probably be rescued by being more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

**I do not think of this question as being a primary fit for RC.SE.** It's well suited where it was asked.

The question is about electric/electronic components and circuitry, not computers. Further not about old ones. It's a perfect good fit at EE.SE.

Don't get me wrong. If it had been asked over here (RC.SE), it would have been on topic because tube computers and their construction are. I might have written an answer. Nonetheless, EE.SE is the best fit.

Also, the process to move between SE sites isn't pull but push based. And it's made for a reason. Most important, it's the OP primary right to decide whom he asks. And the site-asked's decision if *they*  feel it being a proper question for *their* site. If not, they will vote to move it. RC.SE gets rightful only a voice once it has been moved.

The question of being "more appropriate here" can not be asked from the outside, but must come from within the original site and there as its definite "note suitable on this site" counterpart. It's not only the way SE is structured, but also the proper attitude of a polite, non intrusive cooperation.

Since you're member of both sites, you can of course initiate a vote to have it moved ... so: ***do you think that question asking about use of tubes in logic functions is *unfit* for EE.SE?*** If yes, did you vote to mark it as not belonging to EE.SE?

Beside that, it's not really a great question either - at least not as worded - as it seems to be based on a misconception of gates being something other than abstraction level. The only two mostly good answers are in MHO Kuba's and yours.

---

And to vent my inner nerd:

When it comes to tube computers it's important to remember that tubes are there primary for one issue: providing a NOT (well, and amplifying :)). NOT is the only function that needs an active component. Same as with relay based computers.

Comment: "It really comes down to how do you inform people of an interesting question in another forum." This is the reason for posting my question. Snatching a Question from another forum appeared to be the only option for bringing a question before a different audience. I knew that there was a SE Meta, I didn't know there was a RC:Meta. I'm still not confident that creating a post here to say there is an interesting question in another forum is really an appropriate post for RC:Meta.

Comment: @PDP11 Well, Meta.RC _is_ the place todo anything that isn't a question itself. And mentioning a question on another site is quite the right use. Except, the process to move questions between site is push base - that is the other site needs to migrate it over here if _they_ think it's a better fit for RC.SE than their own site.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @PDP11 No sweat. SE structure and handling can be quite non-intuitive, not supported by easy to reach documentation and sometimes outright hidden in plain sight. I for one still can't really master how that chat system works - and I bet there are other useful but hidden tools.

Comment: Regarding your "inner nerd comment", I'll take us further off topic. Some multiple grid variants can be configured as NAND gates. A triode with an indirectly heated cathode can be configured with both grid and cathode drive circuits to become a logic gate.

Comment: @PDP11 Doesn't change the fact, that valves are strictly only needed for NOT. everything else can be made with passive elements. Also, a  'gate'  is never just a transistor alone -same way as a valve alone isn't agate. Both need secondary parts.

Comment: True. Of course the first thing I remembered was diodes can have gain, talk about useless knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

How else might it be done? (in a binary machine)

See the [EDSAC report](https://www.billp.org/ccs/Edsac/Report/index.html#s34) for an example.  In particular, note the truth table for the Adder in section 3.41.  The sum is XOR, carry is AND. Something is computing those values, and the circuit therefore contains logic gates.

But if the question really means, did the builders create discrete units called 'gates' and then wire a lot of those together, that might have a different answer.

Comment: It seems that they had gates for what we now call combinatoric logic, and they conceptualized it that way. What they didn't conceptualize is that the latches and flip-flops for sequential logic could be constructed from gates. They had the flip-flops (the Eccles-Jordan circuit was developed before electronic logic), but the internal construction wasn't built from gates, nor was it conceptualized that way.

Comment: Millman and Taub, Pulse and Digital Circuits, McGraw Hill 1956, Library of Congress 55-11930 VIII 42385. Chapter 13, 'Digital Computer Circuits', Page 414, Figure 13-28 is a one bit register drawn with gates. Effectively a Flip-Flop with Set (Input) and Reset (Clear) connections providing storage and readout of a single binary bit. See http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/columbiaUniv/Millman_Pulse_and_Digital_Circuits_1956.pdf and that leads us back to a SE:Meta discussion on long comments.

Comment: @PDP11 1956 was a decade after the ENIAC. And even then, the presentation in Millman and Taub gave much more attention to Eccles-Jordan type flip flops. You may "effectively" reinterpret parts of the presentation in more modern terms, but that just covers up the fact that the conceptual framework was different back then.

Comment: @PDP11 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/318341/history-of-edge-triggered-d-flip-flop-design-using-three-s-r-latches suggests that the modern edge-triggered flip flop, composed of Boolean gates, appeared in the 1960s. Before that, edge triggering was widespread, but implemented with capacitors, a distinctly non Boolean approach.

Comment: That is the strange thing about your statement "You may "effectively" reinterpret parts of the presentation in more modern term., ...". Years of my training was on vacuum tubes circuits and that included RADAR systems, Moving Target Indicator, VOR, etc., logic gates in first generation computer systems, Karnaugh Maps. This included pulse circuits such the Astable, Mono-stable and Bi-stable. Digital logic for computer systems was a separate subject covering all the standard gates, relay switching circuits, etc. One of our text books was Millman and Taub.

Comment: It was pencil and paper Karnaugh Maps to simplify logic. Transistors were just starting to take off, so our training course was updated to include critical transistor characteristics of Alpha and Beta. Unfortunately by our final year it was h-parameters (life was much simpler in the good old days). Just to give you an indication of my age, my first transceiver was an SCR-522 that covered the 144MHz band (i.e. 2m). I don't "effectively" reinterpret parts in more modern terms because my training and experince was from that era. It is also why I reject the SE accepted answer regarding the ASR-33

Comment: The basics of Boolean Algebra, logic gates, switching circuits, etc., has not changed and were not different then. For example, the logic gates and operation of a simple half-adder is unchanged. What has changed is the technology. Generally I can ignore gate and transmission propagation delays which permits a 'quick and dirty' interpretation. Time is not so easily ignored and must be taken into account. That leads us directly to the answer provided by Kubas.

Comment: @PDP11 Were those systems free of capacitive coupling? A capacitor is not a logic element.

Comment: @PDP11 Are you claiming you *didn't* learn about the Eccles-Jordan circuit? I most certainly learned about it in the 60's.

Comment: @PDP11 You keep arguing that vacuum tube computers *contained* logic gates. That is correct. But they also computed using other kinds of elements: delay circuits, capacitive coupling, Eccles-Jordan circuits, etc. So the answer to "Were Vacuum Tube Computers made of Logic Gates?" is no, they needed other types of circuits.

Comment: 3rd Generation PDP-11/05 has a delay circuit and includes capacitive coupling. By your logic a PDP-11/05 is not made of logic gates as it needed other types of circuits. Taken to the limit, a computer that has an analog power supply is not truly made of logic gates. The Octal Display for the EDUC-8 includes capacitive coupling. By your definition not made of logic gates. Please note I did previously include Bistables when discussing training. Actually a capacitor can be used to store 1 bit and the Williams Tube relied on capacitive coupling for its operation.

Comment: @PDP11 The OP refers to the functional completeness of the NAND gate. You're arguing that even as late as the PDP11/05, the designers weren't relying on the functional completeness of logic gates. Perhaps the real answer to the query is that such reliance is an academic exercise, and real computers don't generally work that way (even though it's possible). Still, I see no sign in the early literature that designers even understood that edge triggered bistables could be constructed from logic gates, while nowadays they are, at least sometimes. The culture has changed.

Comment: Culture hasn't changed but technology has progressed. It is why we still use the terms Von Neumann and Harvard to describe the architecture. These days Harvard systems are not normally constructed using relays or Von Neumann systems with vacuum tubes. You can accept computers can contain circuits that are not basic logic gates without invalidating that they are a digital computer made of logic gates. When introduced to Boolean Algebra and logic gates, time is ignored. In the real world propagation delays exist and impacted computer designers have employed various techniques to build logic.

Comment: Title of the post asked "Were vacuum tube computers made of logic gates?". Answer is Digital computers constructed with vacuum tubes were made of logic gates while the Analogue Computers were not made of logic gates. The title doesn't exclude the analogue.

Comment: The body of the question asked "Now, if we wanted to explain how vacuum tube computer were conceived, before the advent of semi-conductors, would a description based on logic gates be accurate?". For Digital Computers the answer is 'Yes' while for Analogue Computers the answer is 'No'. A description based on logic gates is still accurate for a digital computer based on logic gates that contains circuitry which is not a basic logic gate such as a delay circuit.

Comment: You agreed a digital computer constructed with logic gates can also contain circuitry that is not a basic logic gate. Back to  basics: ALU, Control Unit, I/O, Memory. Which building blocks were not designed with logic gates and how did that impact a digital computer's description that it was/wasn't based on logic gates? As I said a couple of times before with this discussion, we are going to have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @dave remark "But if the question really means, did the builders create discrete units called 'gates' and then wire a lot of those together, that might have a different answer." Looking at the IBM 704 module list, a module could contain multiple basic logic gates and it was used in multiple areas of the system. Nearest equivalent would be early SSI TTL similar in complexity to the level of a 7425. The modules would be installed where that logic function was required. I included the diagram for the simplest IBM 704 logic module in the book. More complex modules are in the engineering manuals.

Comment: @PDP11 "A description based on logic gates is still accurate for a digital computer based on logic gates that contains circuitry which is not a basic logic gate such as a delay circuit." That makes no sense. If the other circuitry is necessary, then a description based on logic gates describes something that won't work.

Comment: So you are now saying a PDP-11 is described as not being based on logic gates as it contains a delay circuit and has capacitors in its circuits. By your definition RetroComputer digital computer systems can never have the description that they are based on logic gates. For example the real 1st, 2nd and 3rd generation computer systems we are discussing can not function without circuits that include elements that are are outside the set of AND, OR and NOT basic gates. Checked VAX-11/780 Engineering Drawings and found nonlogic gate delays. What systems with engineering drawings satisfies you?

Comment: Above @John Doty had stated the Millman and Taub book was irrelevant reference as it is copyright 1956 i.e. the information was too late to have any relevance to vacuum tube computer design in this period. The books Preface, Page viii states "The authors have used almost all the material in this book (in note form and with constant revision) in their classes over the past eight years." Therefore these solid state diode/vacuum tube based logic gates for computer design were accepted practice in this era. http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/columbiaUniv/Millman_Pulse_and_Digital_Circuits_1956.pdf

Comment: @PDP11 And they put logic gates at the end: they were not considered *fundamental*.

Comment: @PDP11 I am saying that the OP is about boolean logic gates as the universal building block. If you're using other building blocks like Eccles-Jordan and delays, gates are not your universal building block. Now, do real computers outside of textbooks actually use boolean elements as the universal building block? Not really. Once you have tri-state busses, you're outside the realm of boolean logic. But as far as I can tell, nobody before IC's even conceived that boolean logic gates *could* be universal.

Comment: You've just stated that real computers are never based on logic gates. The reason I asked you for a system with a complete set of engineering drawings was I'm reasonably confident of finding some circuitry that is not based on AND, OR, NOT basic logic gates. Even if we had access to the engineering drawings for a current Gigabyte X670E, AORUS Extreme motherboard it is highly likely I could find a circuit exception that wasn't a basic logic gate. Then by your definition virtually no real computer has ever been designed using logic gates. Given your position this discussion is a pointless waste.

Comment: I'm not really sure why all of this is attached to my answer in particular, unless it's due to my weasel words of "that might have a different answer". In retrospect, "made of" seems to be the problematic term.

Answer (score 0):

The linked question on ee.se already has some good ones, and as is often the case in life, the best answers begin with *it depends*.  If the question weren't a good fit over there, it would be moved somewhere else (like here).

I imagine there are several others like myself reading both rc.se and ee.se, so to a certain extent you don't need to do anything to "inform people in one forum about a topic of interest in another forum."

You could also have posted something to this stack's chat.

Comment: Must admit ignorance on my part. Before this I didn't know RC Meta existed or was an option.